# Updating selected DB entries django

Tags: python-2.7, django-1.9

I'm stuck at this problem where I have to update only the fields the user selects(from an HTML Form) in the database. I have 6 fields and user may select only one field to update. How should i handle this in code.

I did my research and so far I've found that you can update **if you know what has to be updated**. For example,

```
t = Model.objects.get(id=1)
t.value = 999  # change field
t.save() # this will update only
```

I can update the `value` field which is hard coded in the program. Is there a way to achieve this without hard coding all the fields.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can loop over the field names to update (making sure to validate them) and call `setattr(t, name, value)`.

Comment: should I define setattr method for my model?

Comment: `setattr` is a built-in function. `setattr(x, 'y', z)` is equivalent to `x.y = z`.

Comment: Thanks, That did it :-) `setattr(self, model_columnname, value)`